# User to enter date (mm/dd/yyyy) and validate the data entered

Tags: java, validation, date

Total newbie in programming:
Need to get user to enter date in (mm/dd/yyyy) format.
Need to parseInt() the String and validate whether it is Valid or Invalid Date.
Please help.
To program using java.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ct0280642Assignment
{
    public static void main(String [] dateValidation)
    {
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter a date (mm/dd/yyyy)");
        String uDate = kb.nextLine();
        int userDate = Integer.parseInt(uDate);
        int length = uDate.length();

        if(length != 10)
        {
            System.out.println(uDate+" is a not valid Date");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println(uDate+" is a valid Date");
        }
    }    

}
```

Comment: Date validation or only length validation?

Comment: "Need to parseInt()" - why? Why not use the built-in date parsing functionality? Is this because the assignment is specifically *about* parsing? If so, you'll need to: 1) Split the input into components; 2) Parse each part as an integer; 3) Validate that the components make sense (e.g. not 30th February). Please be specific about what part of that is causing problems. (At the moment it looks like you're trying to parse the whole thing as one integer...)

Comment: Newbie to your search engine too? ;-) Please train your use of that and you may not need ask.

Comment: You require two digit month and day, as in 06/22/2017 or 07/02/2017? Any particular reason you don’t want to allow one digit? Thinking it could be convenient for the user and unambiguous.

Comment: Search Stack Overflow thoroughly before posting.

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ct0280642Assignment {
    public static void main(String[] dateValidation) {
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter a date (mm/dd/yyyy)");
        String uDate = kb.nextLine();
        int userDate = Integer.parseInt(uDate);
        int length = uDate.length();

        try {
            DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
            df.setLenient(false);
            df.parse(uDate);
            System.out.println(uDate + " is a not valid Date");

        } catch (ParseException e) {
            System.out.println(uDate + " is a valid Date");
        }
    }

}
```

Try above code.

Here i had used `DateFormat` function and try to parse that String using `df.parse(uDate)`.If date is valid it automatically transfer that string into `DATE`.

If there is some issue with that string automatically that will generate exception and will be handle by `ParseException` and write message date is not valid.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code. SimpleDateFormat will parse the given date and throws Exception if input is not valid.

```
public static void main(String [] dateValidation)
    {
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
        sdf.setLenient(false);
        System.out.println("Please enter a date (mm/dd/yyyy)");
        String uDate = kb.nextLine();
        try{
            sdf.parse(uDate);
            System.out.println(uDate+" is a valid Date");
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(uDate+" is not a valid Date");
        }
        kb.close();
    }
```

Find the link for documentation on SimpleDateFormat here.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: Please, don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated `SimpleDateFormat` class. `DateTimeFormatter` is much better.

Comment: @OleV.V. We can use DateTimeFormatter but it is only available in Java 8. So let the young ones to learn without struggling if they use Java 7 or lower versions.

Comment: First, the young ones ought to use Java 8 (or later) to get as close to their future as possible. Second, the modern classes are available in Java 6 and 7 through [the ThreeTen Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).

Answer (score 1):

A common way to validate user input is by trying to parse it and seeing if that succeeds. That also works here. Java has nice built-in facilities for parsing dates in various fixed formats, so I suggest you use these:

```
private static final DateTimeFormatter PARSE_FORMATTER
        = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/uuuu");

public static void main(String [] dateValidation)
{
    try (Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in)) {
        System.out.println("Please enter a date (mm/dd/yyyy)");
        String uDate = kb.nextLine();
        try {
            LocalDate.parse(uDate, PARSE_FORMATTER);
            System.out.println(uDate + " is a valid Date");
        } catch (DateTimeParseException dtpe) {
            System.out.println(uDate + " is a not valid Date");
        }
    }
}
```

This accepts `06/17/2017` but rejects `6/17/2017` because the month hasn’t got two digits. Beware that the format pattern string `MM/dd/uuuu` is case sensitive (it has to be uppercase `M` and lowercase `d` and `u`).

If you want to allow one-digit months and days, change the formatter to

```
private static final DateTimeFormatter PARSE_FORMATTER 
        = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("M/d/uuuu");
```

Now all of `7/2/2017`, `07/02/2017` and `12/25/2017` are accepted.

Not related to your question, I have used try-with-resources for making sure the `Scanner` is closed after use. This also closes standard input.

**Question: does this work in Java 8 only?** No, the modern date and time API that I am using has been backported to Java 6 and 7 in [ThreeTen Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) and especially for Android in [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) (and then of course it works in Java 9, due this summer, and later versions…).